# Issue with double value check C++

Tags: c++

I have a condition,

```
double startPoint;
double endPoint; //I have initialised as 0 in constructor

if((startPoint <= 0) && (endPoint <= 0)) 
{
   startPoint = 10;
   endPoint = 100;
}
```

When I build this code in debug mode this condition is satisfying. but in release mode it is not satisfying.

Log shows that these startPoint and endPoint values are 0.0000 and 0.0000.

Comment: Did you assign values into these variables before the `if`? If so, how exactly?

Comment: Are you not initializing them, or is it just a typo?

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please. It's impossible to diagnose from the code you've shown.

Comment: What about `<= 0.0001`? Inspect the rest of the code, or log the if-statement.

Answer (score 5):

You did not initialise the value of your variables, therefore they have an initial random value which can change depending on your build mode (debug/release), try this instead:

```
double startPoint = 0;
double endPoint = 0;
if((startPoint <= 0) && (endPoint <= 0)) 
{
   startPoint = 10;
   endPoint = 100;
}
```